# Multiple errors including an init.py error and a small error with the definition of the term "getmasterPassword

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, sublimetext3

```
import sqlite3, hashlib

from tkinter import \*

 \#Database Code
with sqlite3.connect("password_vault.db") as db:
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS masterpassword(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
password TEXT NOT NULL);
""")

window = Tk()

window.title("Password Vault")

def firstScreen():
window.geometry("250x175")

lbl = Label(window, text="Create Master Password")
lbl.config(anchor=CENTER)
lbl.pack()

txt = Entry(window, width=20)
txt.pack()
txt.focus()

lbl1 = Label(window, text="Re-Enter Password")
lbl1.pack()

txt1 = Entry(window, width=20)
txt1.pack()
txt1.focus()

lbl2 = Label(window)
lbl2.pack()

def savePassword():
   if txt.get() == txt1.get():
       hashedPassword = txt.get

       insert_password = """INSERT INTO masterpassword(password)
       VALUES(?)"""
       cursor.execute(insert_password, [(hashedPassword)])
       db.commit()

       passwordVault()
   else:
       lbl2.config(text="Passwords do not match")

btn = Button(window, text="Save", command=savePassword)
btn.pack(pady=10)

def loginScreen():
window.geometry("250x100")

lbl = Label(window, text="Enter Master Password")
lbl.config(anchor=CENTER)
lbl.pack()

txt = Entry(window, width=20)
txt.pack()
txt.focus()

lbl1 = Label(window)
lbl1.pack()

def getmasterPassword():
    checkHashedPassword = txt.get()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM masterpassword WHERE id = 1 password = ?", [(checkHashedPassword)])
    return cursor.fetchall()


def checkPassword():
 **   match = getmasterPassword() **

    if match:
        passwordVault()
    else:
        txt.delete(0, 'end')
        lbl1.config(text="Wrong Password")

  btn = Button(window, text="Submit", command=checkPassword)
  btn.pack(pady=10)

def passwordVault():
for widget in window.winfo_children():
widget.destroy()
window.geometry("700x350")

lbl = Label(window, text="Password Vault")
lbl.config(anchor=CENTER)
lbl.pack()

cursor.execute("SELECT \* FROM masterpassword")
if cursor.fetchall():
loginScreen()
else:
firstScreen()
window.mainloop()
```

These 3 errors came up after i solved my previous 2

1.

C:\Users####\PycharmProjects\pythonProject8\main.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users####\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1948, in **call**
return self.func(*args) (This Bug has sustained since the previous question)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2.

File "C:\Users####\PycharmProjects\pythonProject8\main.py", line 78, in checkPassword
match = getmasterPassword()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ (I don't understand what's going wrong with this line, since i defined getmasterPassword prior to this line)

3.

File "C:\Users####\PycharmProjects\pythonProject8\main.py", line 73, in getmasterPassword
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM masterpassword WHERE id = 1 password= ?", [check_hashed_password])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "password": syntax error

Comment: `SELECT * FROM masterpassword WHERE id = 1 password = ?` That is not valid SQL.  With two WHERE conditions, you need AND before the second one.  i.e. `WHERE id = 1 AND password = ?`

Comment: The first two errors are just giving you a "roadmap" to where the real error happened.  i.e. it's telling you that function A called function B, and then function B called function C, where the actual error happened.